# LINQ Join With Multiple Where Clause

Tags: linq, join, where-clause

I am struggling once again so any help would be gratefully received.

I have the following LINQ that pulls back a list of data:

```
public static List<tblWeight> GetWeights(string memberid, string locationid, string buyer, string subcategory, string product)
        {

            MyEntity getweights = new MyEntity ();

            var r = (from p in getweights.tblWeights
                     where p.MemberId == memberid &&
                              p.LocationId == locationid
                     select p);

            if (buyer != "Not Specified")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField1 == buyer);

            if (subcategory != "Not Specified")
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField2 == subcategory);

            if (product != "Not Specified")
                r = r.Where(p => p.IDDesc == product);

            return r.ToList();
        }
```

Lovely!

What I would like to do now is based upon this result set and the unit IDs (IDDesc), I then go to tblPurchase, pull back a few columns from tblPurchases and group the columns.

So for example, we have tblWeight looking like so:

```
MemberID    LocationID  Buyer   SubCategory IDDesc
1            1           Cat1   Sub1        ab
1            1           Cat1   Sub1        abc
1            1           Cat1   Sub2        abcd
```

The user makes a search for Sub1 in subcategory and the above LINQ does the trick and pulls back the first two rows from above. Fine.

What I need the LINQ to do now is to go to tblPurchases:

```
MemberID    LocationID  IDDesc  SupplierID  SupplierStatus
1           1          ab        Sup1            Live
1           1          abc       Sup1            Live
1           1          abcd      Sup2            Dead
```

And then pull back the following result so it is joined on MemberID, LocationID and IDDesc but just selects tblPurchases.

Sup1 Live (or all columns in tblPurchases, just grouped/distinct)

I have tried to add in a join and on but no matter how many different variations, I still come across the red squiggle of doom!!!

If anyone can help, beer/kiss is on offer again.

Comment: Barring a human error slip within the table itself, that should never happen. The suppliers would always have a singular, individual status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following LINQ query should do what you want:

```
var result = from w in tblWeight
             where w.SubCategory == "Sub1"
             join p in tblPurchases on
                new { w.MemberID, w.LocationID, w.IDDesc } equals
                new { p.MemberID, p.LocationID, p.IDDesc }
             group p by new { p.SupplierID, p.SupplierStatus } into pg
             select pg.Key;
```

The variable `result` is a list containing tuples of `SupplierID` and `SupplierStatus`.

If you also want to put the conditional parts in there, it gets a little more complicated. Here's how to do it:

```
var weights = from w in tblWeight
              select w;
weights = weights.Where(w => w.SubCategory == "Sub1");
// You can add additional where clauses here.

// Now join with tblPurchases and group by SupplierID and SupplierStatus.
var result =
    weights.Join(tblPurchases,
                 w => new { w.MemberID, w.LocationID, w.IDDesc },
                 p => new { p.MemberID, p.LocationID, p.IDDesc },
                 (w, p) => p)
           .GroupBy(p => new { p.SupplierID, p.SupplierStatus },
                    (k, ps) => new
                                {
                                    k.SupplierID,
                                    k.SupplierStatus,
                                    TotalQty = ps.Sum(p => p.PurchaseQty)
                                });
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me Ronald - top stuff so far. I'm optimistic with the "yet" part of your answer. it's the conditional where part that has really thrown me.

Comment: I added additional stuff that allows you to do the conditional where(s) and also join and group by. I'll skip the kisses but shall I leave you an address to send the beer to ;)

Comment: *Insert expletives here* I would never have come close to getting this!!! 

Genius Ronald...if it works ;  ) Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: You're welcome :) If this answers your question, could you mark it as answered? Thanks.

Comment: Ronald - sorry to bother you again. I had another column, PurchaseQty for each IDDesc in tblPurchases, how would I amned the above code so that this aggregate function is also taking place? apologies for the amount of questions.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `PurchaseQty`.

Comment: Legend. That is fantastic. I owe you more beer/kisses!!

Comment: Please, no kisses ;) Beer would be appreciated.